# GCP monitoring not creating incidents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have created a monitoring policy on GCP so that if an error is observed on any of my Cloud Functions, I get a notification on Slack.

However, even though the errors are output at the log panel of my policy,

- no incidents are created, and
- no notifications are received on Slack.

How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: Can you please share the period you defined on the alert. Here you have defined an alert when an incident is happening for over 5 minutes, but the recent events triggered did not last 5 minutes,  so the alert will not trigger.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem with my log-based alert.